# Function defining: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a square signal (as an array). I am trying the following code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,2000, 100)

def func(x):
    x = np.where(x<500 or x>530, 0, 2)
    return x

y = func(x)
```

unfortunately, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    y = func(x)
  File "test.py", line 20, in func
    x = np.where(x<500. or x>530, 0., 2.)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I do not understand what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can not use `or`** here. `or` is a Python function that evaluates the truthiness of the operands and will, based on that return one of the operands.

You can use the *logical or* (`|`) however, which is implemented by numpy itself:

```
x = np.where((x < 500) | (x > 530), 0, 2)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.